# Typing statistics software for Mac

Tags: gratis, osx

I want statistics about how many words I type on my Mac.

I have been using [Word counter](http://wordcounterapp.com/) but my trial has expired and I was just wondering if there is any free software out there that will let me keep a track of my typing statistics?

The main features I am after are:

- Daily typing stats: the amount of words I've typed for for the day.
- Lets me know what keys are my most vulnerable keys (the ones I use delete button for, most frequently).
- My WPM (words per minute) stats for different programs individually (nice to have but not of utmost importance).
- A log of these stats for at least one month.
- Free